# How to build a shade over more than one rectangle with TIKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

i have the following code, thats build a Rubikscube:

```
\foreach \x in {0,1,2}
{
    \foreach \y in {0,1,2}
    {
        \path[draw,fill=blue] (\y,\x,3) -- (\y+1,\x,3) -- (\y+1,\x+1,3) -- (\y,\x+1,3)--cycle; % breite,länge,tiefe
    }   

    \foreach \y in{0,1,2}
    {   
        \path[draw,fill=green] (\y,3,\x+1) --(\y+1,3,\x+1) -- (\y+1,3,\x) -- (\y,3,\x)--cycle;
    }

    \foreach \y in{0,1,2}
    {   
        \path[draw, fill=red] (3,\y,\x+1) -- (3,\y,\x) -- (3,\y+1,\x) -- (3,\y+1,\x+1)--cycle; % breite,länge,tiefe
    }
}
```

[image: Rubikscube]

Now i want a shade over the complete site. In a further step, the rubikscube will not have the same color on one site. So i can´t make a big shade over the site. I need to have a function with that I can make a shade for every litte rectangle but it looks like a shade over the complete site. I hope you know what I´m looking for.

Maybe there is a option to control the flow of the shade ? so that the left rectangle have the intensity 100% to 80% and the middle rectangle than 80% to 60 % and so on ...

I have to work with TIKZ.

--edit

it need to look like this :

[image: Rubikscube with Shadow]

But this is kind of cheating and it does not allow me to use different colors on one side

```
\path[shade,draw] (0,0,3) -- (3,0,3)--(3,3,3)--(0,3,3)--cycle;
\foreach \x in {0,1,2}
{
    \foreach \y in {0,1,2}
    {
        \path[draw] (\y,\x,3) -- (\y+1,\x,3) -- (\y+1,\x+1,3) -- (\y,\x+1,3)--cycle; % breite,länge,tiefe
    }   

    \foreach \y in{0,1,2}
    {   
        \path[draw,fill=green] (\y,3,\x+1) --(\y+1,3,\x+1) -- (\y+1,3,\x) -- (\y,3,\x)--cycle;
    }

    \foreach \y in{0,1,2}
    {   
        \path[draw, fill=red] (3,\y,\x+1) -- (3,\y,\x) -- (3,\y+1,\x) -- (3,\y+1,\x+1)--cycle; % breite,länge,tiefe
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this one? http://i.stack.imgur.com/jEBuv.png

Comment: Cover it by a transparent fading mask?

Comment: No, that´s exact the shade I don´t want. If it can´t improve, I will do it like you Harish. But I want a shade that is global on one side. So one big shade that goes over the complete side. Of course now I can do this from one corner to diagonal corner but then i have a one colered shade. But in further steps my cube will have different colered rectangles. So this way isn´t possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by my own.
That´s what I wanted:
[image: Rubikscube]

The solution is quite easy.

```
\shade[draw,right color=red!10, left color=red!20]
\shade[draw,right color=orange!20, left color=red!30]
\shade[draw,right color=blue!30, left color=red!40]
```

That´s let the shadow know, with what intensity he needs to start and the next rectangle starts where the before rectangle ends. So it´s a global flow.
Better solutions are still welcome :D